# Java Upgrade from 5 to 8 with Spring

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-5

I am working on a legacy application which is still running on JDK5. As part of our new requirement we need to update it to JDK 8. As per my understanding since Java is backward compatible, this should have worked. When I compiled with JDK 8 , the build was successful. But while launching ,I got the following error :

> Error creating bean with name 'AuthorisationDialogController' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [com/some/application/conf/dispense/dispense-controllers.xml]: Error
>   setting property values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessExceptionsException:
>   PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested
>   propertyAccessExceptions are:
>   [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type
>   [com.some.application.dispense.context.DispenseContextImpl] to
>   required type [com.some.application.admin.AdminContext] for property
>   'context']

My dependencies looks like the following:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymockclassextension</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.micros</groupId>
            <artifactId>aaaa</artifactId>
            <version>${externalVendor}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.micros</groupId>
            <artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
            <version>${externalVendor}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.micros</groupId>
            <artifactId>ccc</artifactId>
            <version>${externalVendor}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.micros</groupId>
            <artifactId>ddd</artifactId>
            <version>${externalVendor}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.micros</groupId>
            <artifactId>eeee</artifactId>
            <version>${externalVendor}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I googled and found out that Spring1.2.6 might not support JDK8. Please can anyone help me what all things I need to take care here. We also have dependency on some external vendor which is built on top of Java5.

Comment: As said in the exception message `Failed to convert property value of type [com.some.application.dispense.context.DispenseContextImpl] to required type [com.some.application.admin.AdminContext] for property 'context'`. You have a type mismatch somewhere, can you find out what class uses said property?

Comment: As i mentioned in the post, this error is not coming with JDK5.

Comment: You should very likely upgrade to a version of Spring that supports Java 8. Maybe not the latest if you keep encountering those issues.

Comment: One thing is for certain: You can't just change java version on a maven project and expect it to just work out of the box.

Comment: Your Spring dependency was released in 2006. Ouch. You probably have a long road ahead I am afraid, unless the codebase is not too big. But if the application is to stay for more years, it will be time well spend. After that however, the best would be to have a policy around updating the dependencies in a regular manner (with time dedicated to evaluate usefulness/measure impact/perform needed changes). That way if it needs continuous maintenance (say being updated to target Java 11 or 17 in a few years, or a dependency being updated due to security concerns), it should be a lot less painful.

Comment: Are you using any java 8 specific annotations such as @propertysource in your spring version 1 ?

Comment: @ThivankaW No . We have not made any code changes. We just upgraded the java version and tried to launch

Comment: Spring 1.2 is not just old it is ancient :). I doubt it runs on Java 8 as it requires ASM and CGLIB versions which probably don't know how to read/process Java 8 bytecode. A lot of things changed between java 5 and java 8. Another thing you probably need to upgrade is your servlet container which also might not directly support Java 8. I would suggest at least to upgrade to Spring 2.0 (which should be a drop-in replacement for 1.2.6 as mainly code was added and not removed/changed). In short only upgrading the runtime to java 8, despite the backwards compatibility, might not always work.

Answer (score 0):

If Spring was a library, you would have seen success.  It is not, it is a framework.

This means that the Spring framework needs to understand the plugins that provide the logic that solves the rest of the "problem" your program addresses.  To do the correct injections and wiring, Spring uses libraries that inspect and configure the plugins written to be managed by Spring.

These libraries do reflection and byte code processing on the plugins.  This means that the Spring framework needs to understand Java 8 bytecode.  Your version of Spring doesn't.  To get a Spring that does, you would update the Apache Maven dependency for Spring; but that will trigger the need to update the plugins to correctly operate with the new Spring version.

In short, you're going to have to migrate a lot more dependencies to newer versions to support Java 8.

Frameworks can be great things, as they can save a lot of time; but, there is an software architecture risk.  If the framework needs updating, all of the plugin components may need modification to migrate to the new version.  Spring is no exception.

This is why some people prefer to leverage libraries; but, libraries are not a panacea, because you often need to decide how to integrate them (which means you're writing your own framework, but that's easier to control the migrate forward than someone else's framework).